# Package manager not working VS2015/VS2013 on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, nuget-package

I have recently updated my system to Windows 10 and installed VS2015 and since this time I have been unable to use package manager in either VS2015 or 2013 (both are currently installed)

For example if I try to install EntityFramework to a new project I get the following error.

**Failed to initialize the PowerShell host. If your PowerShell execution policy setting is set to AllSigned, open the Package Manager Console to initialize the host first.**

If I open the Package Manager Console I get this error.

**The term 'Set-Location' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.**

I have followed some other articles which have suggested setting the Powershell execution policy to RemoteSigned but this has not helped. I have also repaired my VS2015 installation but this has not helped either.

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

For **VS 2013 Update 2013** you should manually install an update 2.8.7 for NuGet Packet Managet. For **VS 2015** - just update NuGet Packet Managet using Tools > Extensions and Updates.

Link to download from GitHub for VS 2013: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases/download/2.8.7/NuGet.Tools.vsix

Link to download from GitHub for VS 2015: 
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/releases/download/3.1.1/NuGet.Tools.vsix

Description of this issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/974

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

Apparently there is a Powershell bug in **Windows 10** version **1511**.

I fixed it (both in VS2013 and VS2015) by installing version **1607**. It can be downloaded here: [Windows 10 Anniversary Update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12387/windows-10-update-history/).

Nuget issue: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3352